# Aligning Radio Buttons to left in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I can align the Button elements to the left to left using `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf`. However I'm unable to do that to the **radio buttons**.

How can I align the radio buttons to left to achieve something like this:

[image]

Here's the layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `horizontal` orientation in your `RadioGroup` like below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#C8E585"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ColdFusion" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flex" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flash" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you.